# Sorting a multidimensional array with array_multisort

Tags: php, sorting, array-multisort

I have an array with following structure:

```
 Array
    (
        [ResultMass] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        //elements and other arrays

                        [FlightsTo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Flight] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [Company] => 4G
                                        //other elements
                                    )

                            )

                        [FlightsBack] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Flight] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [Company] => 4G
                                        //other elements

                                    )

                            )

                    )
                    //other elements of 'resultmass'
               )

        )

    [Error] => 0
)
```

I need to sort ResultMass elements on "FlightsTo->Flight->Company" string of this elements. How can i do this by using array_multisort function? Or it can be done by other method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that via `array_multisort` since your data items are not arrays, they are objects. You can use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to set your own order in your data array.

To set nested order in your case, use this sample:

```
usort($rgData, function($rX, $rY)
{
   if($rX->FlightsTo == $rY->FlightsTo)
   {
      if($rX->Flight == $rY->Flight)
      {
         return $rX->Company<$rY->Company?-1:$rX->Company!=$rY->Company;
      }
      return $rX->Flight<$rY->Flight?-1:1;
   }
   return $rX->FlightsTo<$rY->FlightsTo?-1:1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `usort` function with your own callable method. example below

```
usort(&$array['ResultMass'], function ($a, $b) {
   $a1 = $a->FlightsTo->Flight->Company;
   $b1 = $b->FlightsTo->Flight->Company;
   if ($a1 == $b1) return 0;
   return ($al > $bl) ? +1 : -1;
});
```